# Notepad++ user defined not detecting hexadecimal properly

Tags: hex, notepad++

so i want notepad++ to recognize hexadecimal even when its not spaced from other word let me show you example: 
"

- \^FFFFFFcards\^^,
- **\^FFFFFF** scrolls\^^,
- \^FFFFFFkeys\^^

,

"
My user defined lang detect hexadecimal only there: **\^FFFFFF scrolls\^^** but it does not detect the others like : **\^FFFFFFcards\^^** becouse there's no space between them. Is there a way to tell notepad++ that it should check for " \^ " and six next letters after that mark?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i don't get what you mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)